# Jira SQL custom field overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, jira

I have a task to get overlapping dates from ISSUES, which have "Planned start time" and "Planned finish time" as custom fields.
I am using SQL for JIRA Driver as plugin.
I got this far :
Custom Field ID 10100 is For Planned start time
Custom Field ID 10101 is For Planned finish time

```
SELECT
*
FROM ISSUES i

INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv 
on i.ID=icv.ISSUEID 

INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv2 
on icv2.VALUE >= icv.VALUE

INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv3 
on icv2.VALUE <= icv3.VALUE

WHERE (icv.ISSUEID<>icv2.ISSUEID and icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID=10100 
and icv.CUSTOMFIELDID=10100) and (icv2.ISSUEID<>icv3.ISSUEID 
and icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID=10100 and icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID=10101) 
and icv.ISSUEID=icv3.ISSUEID 
and icv2.ISSUEID= (SELECT ID FROM ISSUES where jql='project=project1' LIMIT 1) //This apears to be the problem
and i.jql='project=project1'
```

It returns a single row, but only if "Planned start time" and "Planned finish time" of 2 issues  match and i am stuck. The problem is that ISSSUEID must be assigned to an existing ISSUE number, JIRA API dictates that.
I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the problem line to use an `IN` construct instead of `=`, as I think that is what you want?

However, you are not actually comparing start or finish times at all. You are making sure that the custom field identifiers (10100 and 10101) match, but not that the values of the custom fields match...

```
...
WHERE (
        icv.ISSUEID <> icv2.ISSUEID 
    AND icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100 
    AND icv.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100
) 
AND (
        icv2.ISSUEID <> icv3.ISSUEID 
    AND icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100 
    AND icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101
) 
AND icv.ISSUEID = icv3.ISSUEID 
AND icv2.ISSUEID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM ISSUES WHERE jql='project=Prakse'
)
AND i.jql='project=Prakse'
...
```

**EDIT** I think I understand the problem a bit better now. The following will give you all issues for which there exists another issue with an overlapping time (Start - Finish):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    ISSUES i 
        INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv 
            ON i.ID = icv.ISSUEID 
                AND icv.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100
        INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv2 
            ON i.ID = icv2.ISSUEID
                AND icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101
    WHERE 
        i.JQL= 'project=project1'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT ID FROM ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv3 
            WHERE 
                icv3.ISSUEID <> i.ID
                AND icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID IN (10100, 10101)   
                AND icv3.VALUE >= icv.VALUE 
                AND icv3.VALUE <= icv2.VALUE
        )
```

**EDIT 2** If the `JIRA` api really needs more specific references to the table keys, then maybe the following will work (I don't have access to JIRA here - just looking at what is logical):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    ISSUES i 
        INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv 
            ON i.ID = icv.ISSUEID 
                AND icv.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100
                AND i.JQL = 'project=project1'
        INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv2 
            ON i.ID = icv2.ISSUEID
                AND icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101
                AND i.JQL = 'project=project1'
    WHERE 
        i.JQL= 'project=project1'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT ID FROM ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv3 
            WHERE 
                icv3.ISSUEID <> i.ID
                AND icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID IN (10100, 10101)   
                AND icv3.VALUE >= icv.VALUE 
                AND icv3.VALUE <= icv2.VALUE
        )
```

**EDIT 3** I am not sure if this will fix the issues, but I have removed the sub-select (exists) statement in favour of an inner join.

```
SELECT
    i.ID, i.JQL, icv.VALUE AS StartTime, icv2.VALUE AS FinishTime
FROM 
    ISSUES i 
        LEFT JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv 
            ON i.ID = icv.ISSUEID 
                AND icv.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100
        LEFT JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv2 
            ON i.ID = icv2.ISSUEID
                AND icv2.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101
        INNER JOIN ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES icv3
            ON i.ID <> icv3.ISSUEID
                AND (icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100 OR icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101)   
                AND icv3.VALUE >= icv.VALUE 
                AND icv3.VALUE <= icv2.VALUE 
 WHERE 
     i.JQL= 'project=project1'
```

Comment: Value matching is done in INNER JOIN statements. JIRA API throws an error when changing  '=' to 'in'. There must be a strict value.

Comment: Right... So, you want the issues which have custom fields (StartTime: 10100 and FinishTime:10101) that overlap? Eg: Issue1(Start 13:00, Finish:15:00), Issue2(Start:12:00, Finish: 14:00)?

Comment: In my second attempt, if JIRA still complains about using the `IN` construct, then change that part of the script to: `(icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10100 OR icv3.CUSTOMFIELDID = 10101) AND ...`

Comment: Yes you are right i want to achieve that. Did as you suggested, still the same error. The error : 
_WARNING: Not enough data to use the JIRA Java API on the table ISSUES
You have to provide some data for one of the following columns at least:
- ID
- KEY
- JQL_

Comment: If you need to provide at least one of the columns (ID, KEY, JQL), then the existing JQL column should be sufficient? https://kintosoft.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SFJ/pages/1343706/Issues

Comment: Turns out that it isn't sufficient. It must be provided on all INNER JOIN instances as well. JIRA is has a very finicky API. That's why i am having so much trouble with it. I replicated the JIRA database on a SQL server and it worked easily, but when it comes to JIRA, things get intense.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The `ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES` requires a reference to `ISSUEID`, the `JQL` reference works ONLY with `ISSUES` table.

Comment: Well - the additions were to add a reference to the `JQL` field in the `ISSUES` table, as part of the join to the `ISSUECUSTOMFIELDVALUES` table. However, if that doesn't work either, then JIRA is making the construction of a dynamic query very difficult.

Comment: Me and my colleague have been at it for some time and only have been able to produce as much as I mentioned in the first question. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: We modified you last submission a bit and it helped, we got further. It doesn't throw an error, but only returns overlapping issues if the last issue added has other issues that overlap. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say __if the last issue added__? I do realise that the JIRA api handles things differently to SQL Server, but I set up a SQL Fiddle here, to make it clearer for myself... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95344/2

Comment: Last Issue inserted into the JIRA system. "the top most issue" if you will.

Comment: Hmm... if you remove the last condition in the query (AND EXISTS), do you get all records that match the JQL condition (not just the last one)?

Comment: Yes, then i get all records. But with that statement I don't get only the last record., but all records that overlap with the last record.